# codesigned errors when using gdb on macos Mojave 10.14

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt, code-signing

I have MacOS Mojave 10.14.
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.2.1

I read many posts on this but I wondered if something is changed in 2019 since most articles are old.
From:
[Eclipse GDB MacOSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877047/eclipse-gdb-macosx-mavericks)

I did:

> Start Keychain Access application
>   (/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app)
>   Open menu /Keychain
>   Access/Certificate Assistant/Create a Certificate (TOP MENU BAR)
>
> Choose a name (gdb-cert in the example) 3.1 Set "Identity Type" to
>   "Self Signed Root" 3.2 Set "Certificate Type" to "Code Signing" 3.3
>   Check the flag "Let me override defaults" 3.4 Click several times on
>   "Continue" until you get to the "Specify a Location For The
>   Certificate screen" then set Keychain to "System" 3.6 Make sure you have the "gdb-cert" in your "System" (left top window)
>
> Select "Get Info" by pressing twice on the fresh made certificate
>   (gdb-cert),
>
> Open the "Trust" item, and set "Code Signing to Always Trust" Close
>   Keychain Access application
>
> Restart "taskgated" application (kill -9) and finally
>   `codesign -s gdb-cert /usr/local/bin/gdb`

But I still get the error:

> lee@l7:~/eclipse-workspace-cdt/my-proj/build$ ./my-proj
>   Hello world
>   (the exe works fine)
>   lee@l7:~/eclipse-workspace-cdt/my-proj/build$ gdb my-proj
>   GNU gdb
>   (GDB) 8.2.1 Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License
>   GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
>   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
>   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. Type "show
>   copying" and "show warranty" for details. This GDB was configured as
>   "x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0". Type "show configuration" for
>   configuration details. For bug reporting instructions, please see:
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/. Find the GDB manual and other
>   documentation resources online at:
>       http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/.
>
> For help, type "help". Type "apropos word" to search for commands
>   related to "word"... Reading symbols from my-proj...done.
>
> (gdb) run
>
> Starting program:
>   /Users/lefla/eclipse-workspace-cdt/my-proj/build/my-proj  Unable to
>   find Mach task port for process-id 12808: (os/kern) failure (0x5). 
>   (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
>
> (gdb) run
>
> Starting program:
>   /Users/lefla/eclipse-workspace-cdt/my-proj/build/my-proj 
>   Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 12819: (os/kern) failure
>   (0x5).  (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))

If gdb is signed, it should be able to fork other processes.
Is killing "taskgated" sufficient (some article mention restarting the machine) ? What is the problem ?

______ EDIT 1
following
https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin
drove me further. Then I hit this problem:
[gdb terminated with signal ?, unknown signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052171/gdb-terminated-with-signal-unknown-signal)
so I created the .gdbinit, and now I get:

> (gdb) run
>   Starting program: /Users/lefla/eclipse-workspace-cdt/my-proj/build/my-proj
>   [New Thread 0x1a03 of process 14140]
>   [New Thread 0x2603 of process 14140]
>   During startup program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

______ EDIT 2
when using gdb 8.0.1, I got:

> my-proj": not in executable format: File format not recognized

seems related to:
https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23746
But gdb 8.3 is just released and it finally works with gdb 8.3

Comment: What is the output of the `codesign` command when you sign `gdb`?

Comment: Now you are probably duplicating this error which requires downgrading gdb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001329/gdb-doesnt-work-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3 answer has instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdb codesigning will need proper entitlements in 10.14+:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin

Edit: Now you are probably duplicating this error which requires downgrading gdb [gdb-doesnt-work-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001329/gdb-doesnt-work-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3)… answer has instructions.

Edit 2: it looks like upgrading to gdb 8.3 should work for you now.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It indeed drives me further. I edited my question accordingly (EDIT1)

Comment: Hi Richard did you have the same problem that I have now ? Thank you

Comment: I have not yet had to use gdb or lldb on my mojave system, but i have used them on sierra...